# Save configuration changes into appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have old .NET 2.0 desktop application that uses standard Settings.settings in a following way:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class AlgebraStatsParams
    {
        public List<GeneratorStats> Params { get; private set; }

        public AlgebraStatsParams()
        {
            Params = new List<GeneratorStats>();
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.AlgebraStats != null)
                foreach (string settings in Properties.Settings.Default.AlgebraStats)
                {
                    GeneratorStats p = GeneratorStats.FromString(settings);
                    Params.Add(p);
                }
            Params.Sort();
        }

        public void SaveToConfig()
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
            Properties.Settings.Default.AlgebraStats.Clear();
            foreach (GeneratorStats p in Params)
                Properties.Settings.Default.AlgebraStats.Add(p.ToString());
            Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```

I porting everything into .NET 6.0 **without dependencies from any non-standard package** or library and decided to use `appsettings.json` as new standard way to store application settings.

```
    internal static class Program
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
```

And to my surprise .NET 6 do not have ability to save changes into `appsettings.json`, as I want in the following code:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class AlgebraStatsParams
    {
        public List<GeneratorStats> Params { get; private set; }

        public AlgebraStatsParams()
        {
            Params = Program.Configuration.GetSection("StatsSettings").Get<List<GeneratorStats>>() ?? new List<GeneratorStats>();
            Params.Sort();
        }

        public void SaveToConfig()
        {
            // I want use SET and SAVE appsettings
            Program.Configuration.GetSection("StatsSettings").Set(Params);
            Program.Configuration.Save();
        }
    }
```

---

So the question: What is **standard way** to save changes into `appsettings.json` configuration (**without external packages**) as simple as it was before in .NET 2.0?

Comment: There are already [several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=save+to+appsettings.json+%5Bc%23%5D) to this question. Did any of those help?

Comment: @JohnWu All that I found so far is contamination of .NET from ASP.NET Web.config way of seeing configuration: [GitHub ASP.NET](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/385). Maybe I should wait several years and .NET Core become more mature?